# How to Upload a photo using Retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit, multipartform-data

I'm using Retrofit in my Android application to communicate with a REST-API.
When user changes his profile picture in my application, I need to send a request and upload new image. This is my service:

```
 @Multipart
 @PATCH("/api/users/{username}/")
 Call<User> changeUserPhoto(@Header("Authorization") String token,@Path("username") String userName , @Part("photo") RequestBody photo);
```

And this is my code to send request:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(GlobalVars.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        UserService userService = retrofit.create(UserService.class);
        Callback<User> callback = new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<User> response, Retrofit retrofit) {

                if (response.isSuccess()) {
                    //do sth
                } else {
                   // do sth else
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
        RequestBody photo = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/image"), new File(imageUir));
        Call<User> call = userService.changeUserPhoto(token, username, photo);

        call.enqueue(callback);
```

But when I send this request to server, REST keeps telling me that photo is not a file and something is wrong with encoding type. 
Can anybody help me how to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `@Body` instead of `@Part`.

```java
@PATCH("/api/users/{username}/")
Call<User> changeUserPhoto(@Header("Authorization") String token,@Path("username") String userName , @Body RequestBody photo);
```

then use `MultipartBuilder` to build the `RequestBody`

```java
RequestBody photo = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/image"), file);
RequestBody body = new MultipartBuilder()
        .type(MultipartBuilder.FORM)
        .addFormDataPart("photo", file.getName(), photo)
        .build();

Call<User> call = userService.changeUserPhoto(token, username, body);
...
```

EDIT:

You can also check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33477879/1425525) to a very similar question.

Answer (score 0):

The better option would be converting bitmap to string and upload as string.

Answer (score -2):

Convert your photo to base64 and upload it as a simple string body.

Comment: If the image is large, this will fail