# Internal Server Error when calling service on retrofit2

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit2 and the problem is that in my `onResponse` I get internal server error.

I have made a Call class i.e

```
public class QuestionCreate {

private String status;
private String result;
private String error;

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getResult() {
    return result;
}

public void setResult(String result) {
    this.result = result;
}

public String getError() {
    return error;
}

public void setError(String error) {
    this.error = error;
}
}
```

My interface is :

```
public interface MultipartApi {

@Multipart
@POST("webapi/groups/questions/create")
Call<QuestionCreate> createQuestion(@Part("questionText") String questionText, @Part("image") byte[] image, @Part("createdBy") String createdBy, @Part("visibleToMembers") String visibleToMembers, @Part("groupId") String groupId, @Part("questionOptions") String questionOptions, @Part("questionTypeId") String questionTypeId, @Part("isAnswerEditable") String isAnswerEditable);

}
```

Well just for more detail , this is my small server method of createQuestion:

```
@POST
@Path("/create")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public JSONObject createQuestion(@FormDataParam("questionText") String questionText, @FormDataParam("image") InputStream image, @FormDataParam("createdBy") String createdBy, @FormDataParam("visibleToMembers") String visibleToMembers, @FormDataParam("groupId") String groupId, @FormDataParam("questionOptions") String questionOptions, @FormDataParam("questionTypeId") String questionTypeId, @FormDataParam("isAnswerEditable") String isAnswerEditable, @FormDataParam("imageFormat") String imageFormat) {
    String message = "";    
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    Question question = new Question();
    System.out.println("Inside createQuestion of class "+this.toString());      
    try {
            question.setQuestionText(questionText);             question.setCreatedBy(createdBy);                               
            question.setVisibleToMembers(visibleToMembers);
            question.setGroupId(groupId);
            question.setQuestionOptions(questionOptions);
            question.setQuestionTypeId(questionTypeId); 
            question.setIsAnswerEditable(isAnswerEditable);             
            DBConnection.insertQuestion(question, image, servletContext, imageFormat);
            message = "Question Created";
            obj.put("status", 1);
            obj.put("result", message);
            return obj;
        } catch(SQLException sqle){
            System.out.println("createQuestion catch sqle");
            message = "A problem occured while creating question : "+sqle.getMessage();
            try {
                obj.put("status", 501);
                obj.put("error", message);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }               
            return obj;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("Inside createQuestion catch  "+e.getMessage());
            message = "A problem occured while creating question : "+e.getMessage();
            try {
                obj.put("status", 501);
                obj.put("error", message);
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }               
            return obj;
        }       
}
```

and i am calling my service like:

```
                Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(URLConstants.URL_BASE+"/")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();

            MultipartApi multipartApi = retrofit.create(MultipartApi.class);

            Call<QuestionCreate> req = multipartApi.createQuestion(question.getQuestionText(), inputStream, question.getCreatedBy(), question.getVisibleToMembers(), question.getGroupId(), question.getQuestionOptions(), question.getQuestionTypeId(), question.getIsAnswerEditable());
            req.enqueue(new Callback<QuestionCreate>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<QuestionCreate> call, Response<QuestionCreate> response) {
                    String str = response.message();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<QuestionCreate> call, Throwable t) {
                     //Print Error
                }
            });
```

I have just started learning about it yesterday so there must be some mistakes. So I have a few questions:

1. How do I just send a map of data (like in StringRequest of volley)?
2. How do I get string as a response because I didn't want a model class for this purpose i.e how do I get the just json string?
3. What could be the reason for getting internal server error?

Thank you.

Comment: If you are getting an Internal Server Error that means that something went wrong at the server end and not at your end. You should either post the error message sent by the server or debug on the server side as to what is going wrong.

Comment: I think you have to use RequestBody instead of byte array. Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33482385/how-to-upload-a-photo-using-retrofit

Comment: what's wrong with bytes :/

Comment: and what about my other questions

Comment: this is weird but now my response is ok O.o

Comment: anyways can u answer my other two questions