# Issue in Uploading Image in retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit, image-uploading, retrofit2

Firstly I am using Retrofit 2.0,In that Image is first Converted to String as String is need to pass in url.**The main issue is when the whole FileByte(Which is String of Image) is passes to Interface url and gets the URL which is just half FileBytes we get i.e URL is not fully obtain** just look at the code

Here it Interface Definition to Upload Image:

```
public interface ApiConfig {
 @POST("UploadDocument")
 Call<List<ServerResponse>> uploadFile(
          @Query("employeeid") String employeeid            
        , @Query("filename") String filename
        , @Query("extention") String extention
        , @Query("fileBytes") String fileBytes
);
}
```

Now converted Image to String Code:

```
 try {
                Bitmap bitmaps = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
                final ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmaps.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, stream);
                byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
                mediaPath = GetFilePathFromDevice.getPath(MainActivity.this, data.getData());
                Log.e("encoding", mediaPath);
                filepath.setText(mediaPath);
                encodeded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, 0);/*Here it is Converted to String*/
                imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmaps);
                Log.e("encoding", encodeded);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Here is Setter code on BtnUpload:

```
  btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String Filename = mediaPath.substring(mediaPath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            Filename = stripExtension(Filename);
            String extension = mediaPath.substring(mediaPath.lastIndexOf("."));
            serverResponse.setFilename(Filename);                
            serverResponse.setExtention(extension);
            serverResponse.setFileBytes(encodeded);
            serverResponse.setEmployeeid("2028");
            uploadFile(serverResponse);
     });
```

Here is the main code where parameters passes through interface:

```
 Call<List<ServerResponse>> call = getResponse.uploadFile(serverResponse.getEmployeeid()
                                                         , serverResponse.getFilename()
                                                         , serverResponse.getExtention()
                                                         , serverResponse.getFileBytes());

 Log.e("url", String.valueOf(call.request().url()));
```

So here we Go I am posting log of **Encoding** When Image is converted into Strings.

```
E/encoding: Encoding-iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAADNAAAAcwCAIAAAAgP8/oAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAgAElEQVR4
                                                                             nKS93ZokN44leACauUempFL11ExVX86z791e7XP1xfS2SqmMcDcCZy8AkDTzSHXPrH36Uh7uZjQS
                                                                             BPF7CMr/9X//PwAcBABARKASH0gCUFURASCEqhIW38c9cQGIL+PzuEREVUkC8SvjXSRF2toOABcH
                                                                             sGEfX3o1RjL6k13K55Tktm3xirjH3c1MRLZtMzN3J6mQ8RatXpOMX+t1LRtVFeEYyNrPcZFsLVtY
                                                                             BxuPR7MkB+kAyDafdZvkcvfspGrcn69TubScH2hmlhMEjQ6o6ons1DE6EQ76tNbi89qxQYR1mCuJ
                                                                             Rj8H/UU5pl7Z1keinXgw3mVm443xIb4Z1Iibx+Pubpzz4t1I9t5774RFT3rv8WV1ngB678dxUKT3
                                                                             Hq8g3czMjjkvMADwOV7VzczshYzBToP4JAVOUrCTZE0IANbY3d0dItLapF5r+6BbjM69x1zEK0RE
                                                                             FOP+fbl/0ATLehyfB8+Pfgafr7O2rs24dt1Xph0vig9+/p7kbdsuDY7Bxj2ttcHGAFgdXnu4Pksy
                                                                             ZiGEwyabu/fk1RMLjU62RaoE3dZu03zQUwk5i6Pb7c3dSbvyNiz6rKrU+dNg7ZgtkhAHILGIYCIS
                                                                             Y6REU7M/VBGR+B+JsTaTEC6qqvDLxOXalO11lkVE4ReCFEtEkxARiI7Pm+iYi0H5oE/vvbW2bZs7
                                                                             psDpV8qn3Nha8PkUF/FA8vBcsMnYC9usr07eAFGyd7CNu2vcg0YyBnlrNwDUVQJLyORxAVN8NbRV
                                                                             jK8cCEBeRLfiJOXmZ53fO6fuo0rwFc9NqW4ALFcNRSRmX+vZhT7V1LxszKnqNoWDzHmPZxsWyf/y
                                                                             YXB1vD1aDiE2+o/J+PPx4IehetCCnurugwwx6aVExqIOCrfR4K5tyJN1jV/IPt479OOV5crqADAk
                                                                             dqwud5cWrJcjHcplFQXjXetiIQkVEWmtxdSOpRHtSykdkvS1y1MXxM2zA5+ZOrFS8qeloXjKaUOi
                                                                             VudtkaYN5yWDZSmRNDNp1/6M+3G98u3uHorq1OYiutclPNjmRDrAMCncIOPVF4k0VGdLe2/O+BB3
                                                                             lwla+Ty+lJDePN3p7pTUMjGD6ywAQMOVDgtltBhyvLHWna5DGNR4/TL/PNF59jnkwKUFDHvDr/Ic
                                                                             ZVqMGYw/nf2VUAC2dgs7NoTLMnGrPIzOeNB/ErkW0ZQJ4iRDBVWnNxHhYnGNVwxCrdMkIcr8ZDe6
                                                                             u277OuOT5mjrSOelHGNfx9vQ1j/H7U105dtJcz2ZQLP91XdgKdOFdcerL/zAxWK5fL+2FvLkQjQA
                                                                             0CsLrfcMysxfEfzj441DPJoZxEVk2Kvu7pTjOI7H8+Pj4/sfv/fee38+Hg/Czew4jo+PDx7P9/f3
                                                                             7//87d/+7d++/fO3x+PRuy9XDw/C3UMuOY6lh4tf87oiJGTL5Jby7xaPZqE8GDKzjW/CXxBZhY+L
                                                                             SHLm8lS+cCHXhVsGP6zujIEoaVz3EUDDMq6QpQKQyvA98wUAsEjjHBQUZUtcJhcvmu56ybHcrD+4
                                                                             Z1E8nPzw4zbX+1/afFUI+X0DAG0gs9tNp1jLLwkkxfInEZDTaCJj8vIt8RlAeR+KtBtVFaU0Ueta
                                                                             VVtrsu0Attv+9vb2P/7n//zHP/7B23a/3/3tLiL2df/y5cuxyb7vt5+/fvnyZdv31tq+7/u+rxJp
                                                                             fBARanP37hbTQ7LXdJMMiy4sZIOQNMrwNMecigiampkbRCR0btj5jqlEkKzYVHUTBUCVoaHmSxcJ
                                                                             OV4RFt1q6Xm+uo32DcbSETfZSZqiteYqAJqIiDSfLGoKAIfE6gXJRkj5KdZERPZ9F5GbY9g/JrNj
                                                                             EZM52AeVtphNQkQ2bWnGuEvbwvse4xLG90rSkXRT1WhHXLho3lcZHv1UVREFcGsbAIsLJGkS9k/r
                                                                             vYcfwQrikGzpVdHM2I9B/I1C8iejiPz1YSR/MW+t/Xdt+75/1Q8ReXu+997b8Xg+n41G8oYngJv1
                                                                             1toXbiRv7GaGfvTe0Q+Scjx77yFPcH/713/917dff/3y5cv+00+32832m6rq1lTVRFV13/dt227b
                                                                             7u7hO1lI8rxwHEfEBJzd3fHsz+cTj+fHx4e9Px6Pxx+///OPP/4Isu/7HUDMHVRaa9ttb6293e7b
                                                                             tsVEf/36VUSMvm2by5zxFlE4AkA/Hh8fH8+P7+6uEHdnN/chCJP9gqtJhgWMhtZarIv97f7169f9
                                                                             669SMcPyi6edHNwYvGTPx8fHBx+P4zis98fj8Xz/OI5j+O9h5wAzwAdA9TbkbXQp/Ttty/I/6YWw
                                                                             1Un27qP94L0ReiJJxipr8cKVLVfjJ9l+2Bin0NA0FYaJtbK6u38aPwQQtpmHf721HIPI7e0eLWzb
                                                                             9vb1y77vwzMyswbpvb+/v5uZQnrvG9XMcknSxxKrCFiInWkPiy+daXq/37/+9NPb29t230Uk5Hbb
                                                                             t9vttm3bIrustbbvDcBxHM/ns9vzOI7e+/P5/Pj4cPewiDYBSXPvvRclxcwierzf2u12u7+93W63
                                                                             /X5rrdHv27bpvoVEaq3pvm/btr/dVVUJd6dNj2bbwh7uvffj+TyO4zg+eu+K3nundzN7//j28fHh
                                                                             x9Pd1XeSgvBSFYDo9vb29tN/+/XLly96u4uItrZt26bbiMHG+h1/xuSvnqO79+M4jsP6x+Px6I+g
                                                                             xjPucXcV+e233z7++A5AjO4eMlnb/X6/t/vtfr+HxOCmALS12+12u91aa7JtrbVYesFX6QtHYNFz
                                                                             invvz4+HmUH4eDyez6eI7GiPx+P9j+/fvn17/PG99+4VDnV3qLbW9tvt69evX37+ad937vdQpTHI
                                                                             1tp2v93v91jj0YFNszPB2r13msVqej6fj8ej9z7iuiTFaGb2eP6v//W/nt++j3h1dLu1dr/f//b3
                                                                             /3G73bb71lrzJq012ZqqNr1HkCqEz9CqoQvipSh+IOl2PB6Px+MRUtrd7ejHcaDb8/n8+P798Xj0
                                                                             5/M4jliGYaVYk59//vmvf//vX79+jfUVMZy//OUvt9sNIq01l+k9SWUW4u1mJvDjOOzx7L1HVCHk
                                                                             Zyiv/jxIfv/j93//938/Hu/HcaQhRAVgYTxRRWT76e1vf/vbL7/80lpr26aqsrV930Vb8GFYPovn
                                                                             MqXZx/F8f3/vj6eZqdDd5TAz47P33nl0M3v//dvvv/8eob8MeKKpKigkf/7Lr//4xz9++Ze/ttaw
                                                                             tX3fnyFCd73f723fQrarqpFmlhrKPILt7t7Yeu+H9ViVx3HwcZjZDfrx8fH+++8hrIDhiouIIKh6
                                                                             2758+fLll798+fLl9ra31mIuauq1tebMiScZsivlWz9IOsw9O2N2kLzr1nv3ox/H8Xz/+OOPP473
                                                                             j5BF0T6HOG66bRvuX3755Ze//Mtfv3792tomItr2YL9hX9H7kIQdh5mhO0n0w8y6W++9i5kZzY/j
                                                                             8G9/vL+/8/vjOA7xG5neqAVH7bdt2+4/fdn3Hdu2bdvtp7f7/b7fbvf7XbFN06hN/Wt2DA6MnAiA
                                                                             3vvz++P79+/9+RARMTez/vHx/v5+PJ5mZnRVjYRE2E7bfrvf79jb/X5/+8vPX79+bbd9iBqpHNZU
                                                                             fD38O3f343iQRMSjzI7j8ONJssFIPt6/ffv27f39I+iAitvTwyrYW2vt/vbrr7/++ve/3e93iquq
                                                                             HU8Raft2v9/bflfV4LeRVggP91lLWMx/++23f/7zn+4envgGxkp8Pp/9yHgmybDt7z/95e9///vb
                                                                             ly8x48M2Q8m6MM9KuEmDhh8d9ueY9++///79+/fn4yEijd57f7x/PB6P1iXkIclwsvW23e/3/cvb
                                                                             vu9y30OyBVX3fQ+7Mdb4toXaacNSEnN3VyPJj/f3b9++qVkM7OPj4/n8CAff3WO99+fRe0/RTKjq
                                                                             /Zeffv7557Ao9vuX2+0mt83dI3gXlrwqWmtbSCTdQm6HZiH5fD7f
```

And Forming URL is:

```
E/url: http://192.168.1.55:81/services/appservices.asmx/UploadDocument?employeeid=2028&filename=IMG_20161130_101148&extention=.jpg&fileBytes=iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAADNAAAAcwCAIAAAAgP8/oAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAgAElEQVR4%0AnKS93ZokN44leACauUempFL11ExVX86z791e7XP1xfS2SqmMcDcCZy8AkDTzSHXPrH36Uh7uZjQS%0ABPF7CMr/9X//PwAcBABARKASH0gCUFURASCEqhIW38c9cQGIL%2BPzuEREVUkC8SvjXSRF2toOABcH%0AsGEfX3o1RjL6k13K55Tktm3xirjH3c1MRLZtMzN3J6mQ8RatXpOMX%2Bt1LRtVFeEYyNrPcZFsLVtY%0ABxuPR7MkB%2BkAyDafdZvkcvfspGrcn69TubScH2hmlhMEjQ6o6ons1DE6EQ76tNbi89qxQYR1mCuJ%0ARj8H/UU5pl7Z1keinXgw3mVm443xIb4Z1Iibx%2BPubpzz4t1I9t5774RFT3rv8WV1ngB678dxUKT3%0AHq8g3czMjjkvMADwOV7VzczshYzBToP4JAVOUrCTZE0IANbY3d0dItLapF5r%2B6BbjM69x1zEK0RE%0AFOP%2Bfbl/0ATLehyfB8%2BPfgafr7O2rs24dt1Xph0vig9%2B/p7kbdsuDY7Bxj2ttcHGAFgdXnu4Pksy%0AZiGEwyabu/fk1RMLjU62RaoE3dZu03zQUwk5i6Pb7c3dSbvyNiz6rKrU%2BdNg7ZgtkhAHILGIYCIS%0AY6REU7M/VBGR%2BB%2BJsTaTEC6qqvDLxOXalO11lkVE4ReCFEtEkxARiI7Pm%2BiYi0H5oE/vvbW2bZs7%0ApsDpV8qn3Nha8PkUF/FA8vBcsMnYC9usr07eAFGyd7CNu2vcg0YyBnlrNwDUVQJLyORxAVN8NbRV%0AjK8cCEBeRLfiJOXmZ53fO6fuo0rwFc9NqW4ALFcNRSRmX%2BvZhT7V1LxszKnqNoWDzHmPZxsWyf/y%0AYXB1vD1aDiE2%2Bo/J%2BPPx4IehetCCnurugwwx6aVExqIOCrfR4K5tyJN1jV/IPt479OOV5crqADAk%0Adqwud5cWrJcjHcplFQXjXetiIQkVEWmtxdSOpRHtSykdkvS1y1MXxM2zA5%2BZOrFS8qeloXjKaUOi%0AVudtkaYN5yWDZSmRNDNp1/6M%2B3G98u3uHorq1OYiutclPNjmRDrAMCncIOPVF4k0VGdLe2/O%2BBB3%0Alwla%2BTy%2BlJDePN3p7pTUMjGD6ywAQMOVDgtltBhyvLHWna5DGNR4/TL/PNF59jnkwKUFDHvDr/Ic%0AZVqMGYw/nf2VUAC2dgs7NoTLMnGrPIzOeNB/ErkW0ZQJ4iRDBVWnNxHhYnGNVwxCrdMkIcr8ZDe6%0Au277OuOT5mjrSOelHGNfx9vQ1j/H7U105dtJcz2ZQLP91XdgKdOFdcerL/zAxWK5fL%2B2FvLkQjQA%0A0CsLrfcMysxfEfzj441DPJoZxEVk2Kvu7pTjOI7H8%2BPj4/sfv/fee38%2BHg/Czew4jo%2BPDx7P9/f3%0A7//87d/%2B7d%2B%2B/fO3x%2BPRuy9XDw/C3UMuOY6lh4tf87oiJGTL5Jby7xaPZqE8GDKzjW/CXxBZhY%2BL%0ASHLm8lS%2BcCHXhVsGP6zujIEoaVz3EUDDMq6QpQKQyvA98wUAsEjjHBQUZUtcJhcvmu56ybHcrD%2B4%0AZ1E8nPzw4zbX%2B1/afFUI%2BX0DAG0gs9tNp1jLLwkkxfInEZDTaCJj8vIt8RlAeR%2BKtBtVFaU0Ueta%0AVVtrsu0Attv%2B9vb2P/7n//zHP/7B23a/3/3tLiL2df/y5cuxyb7vt5%2B/fvnyZdv31tq%2B7/u%2BrxJp%0AfBARanP37hbTQ7LXdJMMiy4sZIOQNMrwNMecigiampkbRCR0btj5jqlEkKzYVHUTBUCVoaHmSxcJ%0AOV4RFt1q6Xm%2Buo32DcbSETfZSZqiteYqAJqIiDSfLGoKAIfE6gXJRkj5KdZERPZ9F5GbY9g/JrNj%0AEZM52AeVtphNQkQ2bWnGuEvbwvse4xLG90rSkXRT1WhHXLho3lcZHv1UVREFcGsbAIsLJGkS9k/r%0AvYcfwQrikGzpVdHM2I9B/I1C8iejiPz1YSR/MW%2Bt/Xdt%2B75/1Q8ReXu%2B997b8Xg%2Bn41G8oYngJv1%0A1toXbiRv7GaGfvTe0Q%2BScjx77yFPcH/713/917dff/3y5cv%2B00%2B32832m6rq1lTVRFV13/dt227b%0A7u7hO1lI8rxwHEfEBJzd3fHsz%2BcTj%2BfHx4e9Px6Pxx%2B///OPP/4Isu/7HUDMHVRaa9ttb6293e7b%0AtsVEf/36VUSMvm2by5zxFlE4AkA/Hh8fH8%2BP7%2B6uEHdnN/chCJP9gqtJhgWMhtZarIv97f7169f9%0A669SMcPyi6edHNwYvGTPx8fHBx%2BP4zis98fj8Xz/OI5j%2BO9h5wAzwAdA9TbkbXQp/Ttty/I/6YWw%0A1Un27qP94L0ReiJJxipr8cKVLVfjJ9l%2B2Bin0NA0FYaJtbK6u38aPwQQtpmHf721HIPI7e0eLWzb%0A9vb1y77vwzMyswbpvb%2B/v5uZQnrvG9XMcknSxxKrCFiInWkPiy%2BdaXq/37/%2B9NPb29t230Uk5Hbb%0At9vttm3bIrustbbvDcBxHM/ns9vzOI7e%2B/P5/Pj4cPewiDYBSXPvvRclxcwierzf2u12u7%2B93W63%0A/X5rrdHv27bpvoVEaq3pvm/btr/dVVUJd6dNj2bbwh7uvffj%2BTyO4zg%2Beu%2BK3nundzN7//j28fHh%0Ax9Pd1XeSgvBSFYDo9vb29tN/%2B/XLly96u4uItrZt26bbiMHG%2Bh1/xuSvnqO79%2BM4jsP6x%2BPx6I%2Bg%0AxjPucXcV%2Be233z7%2B%2BA5AjO4eMlnb/X6/t/vtfr%2BHxOCmALS12%2B12u91aa7JtrbVYesFX6QtHYNFz%0Ainvvz4%2BHmUH4eDyez6eI7GiPx%2BP9j%2B/fvn17/PG99%2B4VDnV3qLbW9tvt69evX37%2Bad937vdQpTHI%0A1tp2v93v91jj0YFNszPB2r13msVqej6fj8ej9z7iuiTFaGb2eP6v//W/nt%2B%2Bj3h1dLu1dr/f//b3%0A/3G73bb71lrzJq012ZqqNr1HkCqEz9CqoQvipSh%2BIOl2PB6Px%2BMRUtrd7ejHcaDb8/n8%2BP798Xj0%0A5/M4jliGYaVYk59//vmvf//vX79%2BjfUVMZy//OUvt9sNIq01l%2Bk9SWUW4u1mJvDjOOzx7L1HVCHk%0AZyiv/jxIfv/j93//938/Hu/HcaQhRAVgYTxRRWT76e1vf/vbL7/80lpr26aqsrV930Vb8GFYPovn%0AMqXZx/F8f3/vj6eZqdDd5TAz47P33nl0M3v//dvvv/8eob8MeKKpKigkf/7Lr
```

The URL filebytes is halfly obtain so how can i solve this issue hope you understand whats the problem.Everything is alright except this...And it replaces **%oA** in place of Space in FileBytes.

**Edited: Now I am Passing byte[] instead of String**

```
@Query("fileBytes") byte[] fileBytes
```

The recent URL is Like:

```
E/url: http://192.168.1.55:81/services/appservices.asmx/UploadFile?employeeid=2028&filename=IMG_20170302_152931&extention=.jpg&fileBytes=-1&fileBytes=-40&fileBytes=-1&fileBytes=-32&fileBytes=0&fileBytes=16&fileBytes=74&fileBytes=70&fileBytes=73&fileBytes=70&fileBytes=0&fileBytes=1&fileBytes=1&fileBytes=0&fileBytes=0&fileBytes=1&fileBytes=0&fileBytes=1&fileBytes=0&fileBytes=0&fileBytes=-1&fileBytes=-37&fileBytes=0&fileBytes=67&fileBytes=0&fileBytes=16&fileBytes=11&fileBytes=12&fileBytes=14&fileBytes=12&fileBytes=10&fileBytes=16&fileBytes=14&fileBytes=13&fileBytes=14&fileBytes=18&fileBytes=17&fileBytes=16&fileBytes=19&fileBytes=24&fileBytes=40&fileBytes=26&fileBytes=24&fileBytes=22&fileBytes=22&fileBytes=24&fileBytes=49&fileBytes=35&fileBytes=37&fileBytes=29&fileBytes=40&fileBytes=58&fileBytes=51&fileBytes=61&fileBytes=60&fileBytes=57&fileBytes=51&fileBytes=56&fileBytes=55&fileBytes=64&fileBytes=72&fileBytes=92&fileBytes=78&fileBytes=64&fileBytes=68&fileBytes=87&fileBytes=69&fileBytes=55&fileBytes=56&fileBytes=80&fileBytes=109&fileBytes=81&fileBytes=87&fileBytes=95&fileBytes=98&fileBytes=103&fileBytes=104&fileBytes=103&fileBytes=62&fileBytes=77&fileBytes=113&fileBytes=121&fileBytes=112&fileBytes=100&fileBytes=120&fileBytes=92&fileBytes=101&fileBytes=103&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=-1&fileBytes=-37&fileBytes=0&fileBytes=67&fileBytes=1&fileBytes=17&fileBytes=18&fileBytes=18&fileBytes=24&fileBytes=21&fileBytes=24&fileBytes=47&fileBytes=26&fileBytes=26&fileBytes=47&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=66&fileBytes=56&fileBytes=66&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=99&fileBytes=-1&fileBytes=-64&fileBytes=0&fileBytes=17&fileBytes=8&fileBytes=5&fileBytes=-96&fileBytes=10&fileBytes=0&fileBytes=3&fileBytes=1&fileBytes=34&fileBytes=0&fileBytes=2&fileBytes=17&fileBytes=1&fileBytes=3&fileBytes=17&fileBytes=1&fileBytes=-1&fileBytes=-60&fileBytes=0&fileBytes=31&fileBytes=0&fileBytes=0&fileBytes=1&fileBytes=5&fileBytes=1&fileBytes=1&fileBytes=1&fileBytes=1&fileBytes=1&fileBytes=1&fileBytes=0&fileBytes=0&fileBytes=0&fileBytes=0&fileBytes=0&fileBytes=0&fileBytes=0&fileBytes=0&fileBytes=1&fileBytes=2&fileBytes=3&fileBytes=4&fileBytes=5&fileBytes=6&fileBytes=7&fileBytes=8&fileBytes=9&fileBytes=10&fileBytes=11&fileBytes=-1&fileBytes=-60&fileBytes=0&fileBytes=-75&fileBytes=16&fileBytes=0&fileBytes=2&fileBytes=1&fileBytes=3&fileBytes=3&fileBytes=2&fileBytes=4&fileBytes=3&fileBytes=5&fileBytes=5&fileBytes=4&fileBytes=4&fileBytes=0&fileBytes=0&fileBytes=1&fileBytes=125&fileBytes=1&fileBytes=2&fileBytes=3&fileBytes=0&fileBytes=4&fileBytes=17&fileBytes=5&fileBytes=18&fileBytes=33&fileBytes=49&fileBytes=65&fileBytes=6&fileBytes=19&fileBytes=81&fileBytes=97&fileBytes=7&fileBytes=34&fileBytes=113&fileBytes=20&fileBytes=50&fileBytes=-127&fileBytes=-111&fileBytes=-95&fileBytes=8&fileBytes=35&fileBytes=66&fileBytes=-79&fileBytes=-63&fileBytes=21&fileBytes=82&fileBytes=-47&fileBytes=-16&fileBytes=36&fileBytes=51&fileBytes=98&fileBytes=114&fileBytes=-126&fileBytes=9&fileBytes=10&fileBytes=22&fileBytes=23&fileBytes=24&fileBytes=25&fileBytes=26&fileBytes=37&fileBytes=38&fileBy
```

Thank you

Comment: But by an old method httpclient I had passed same string as parameter and worked fined....Then why isnt in this retrofit?

Comment: Use multi-part in retrofit to upload the image

Comment: Yes but sir is there anyway to use in String format only??

Comment: Use @Multipart to upload image to backend side and send image as a FILE format, like this Call<ResponseBody> changeProfilePicture(@Part MultipartBody.Part file);

Comment: do see my Edited Question,I Had passed byte[] instead of String now the url is different...not getting whats the problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33482385/how-to-upload-a-photo-using-retrofit

Comment: by using RequestBody instead of byte[] does it will solve?? @Chirag.T

Comment: yes in this link that give you perfect sample of uploading image please try maybe it's work...

Comment: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server

it's work also.. @AbhishekBardolia

Comment: I am bit confuse i mean i had seen ur link Can you show me a bit demo code using byte[] in this example??Please @Chirag.T

Comment: Not working my friend.... @Chirag.T